# How do I install libspotify on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, spotify, homebrew

I'am trying to install libspotify on Mac OSX Lion. I want to use spotify api in a Python script. When I try installing pyspotify, it says:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pyspotify.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pyspotify.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pyspotify.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pyspotify.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pyspotify.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'spotify._spotify' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Isrc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/module.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
src/module.c:20:10: fatal error: 'spotify/api.h' file not found
#include "spotify/api.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried to install libspotify using brew...

```
brew install libspotify
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you install it with brew, as you say, or just copy the libspotify.framework to /Library/Frameworks

Now you should be able to include the lib like:

```
#include <libspotify/api.h>
```